# Avoid ObservableCollection in MVVM Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Model class with a collection and a ViewModel wrapper class for that Model class. The wrapper class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a wrapper property for every property in the model class. I've implemented it this way to make the model class as independent from any WPF namespace as possible, because these classes are also used in another project (a windows service). The implementation (simplified) looks like this:

**Model**

```
public class FbiDirectory
{
    private string type;
    private ObservableCollection<PluginValue> pluginValues = new ObservableCollection<PluginValue>();

    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.type;
        }

        set
        {
            this.type = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PluginValue> PluginValues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pluginValues;
        }

        set
        {
            this.pluginValues = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel wrapper**

```
public class FbiDirectoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private FbiDirectory fbiDirectory = new FbiDirectory();

    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fbiDirectory.Type;
        }

        set
        {
            this.fbiDirectory.Type = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("Type");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PluginValue> PluginValues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fbiDirectory.PluginValues;
        }

        set
        {
            this.fbiDirectory.PluginValues = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("PluginValues");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

My question is if there is a way to make the `PluginValues` collection in the Model of type `List` and still have the features of `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel. Perhaps with some sort of converter or casting or anything like this.

Comment: partial class??

Comment: Why do you want to have it this way ?

Comment: @BraveHeart I need the Model classes in another project, too. The WPF application is used to set all needed values in the model classes, which are then serialized to a XML file. This file is then deserialized by a WindowsService and the settings are used to execute some tasks. But I don't want to import some WPF specific references in the Windows Service project just to use observable collections

Comment: You *don't* need an ObservableCollection for binding, as long as you raise the appropriate notification event for the property. A List<> or array will do just as well. ObservableCollection raises the event every time the collection is modified. You can do the same in code if you want

Comment: ObservableCollection is in namespace `System.Collections.ObjectModel` and in assembly `System.dll`. That's not WPF, but core .NET Framework.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But how would I know if an item is added to the collection to raise an event?

Comment: @Clemes You're right. I thought `INotifyPropertyChanged` was in a WPF specific namespace, but it is also in System.dll. I'll consider to leave it this way then.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé who is going to add that item? Such an operation should be a Command or a method on the ViewModel itself

Comment: @Clemens not at all, it's a VALID question. Frameworks like Caliburn.Micro *don't* use ObservableCollection. It's *not* a requirement for MVVM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, they have a *different* implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged. You can even write you own implementation, but for what reason?

Comment: @Clemens no. No different than the one posted here, which raises the event when the property is *set*. ObservableCollection helps in *some* scenarios. It doesn't help if eg the items of the collection are ViewModels themselves and the view uses composition

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The operation is implemented as a Command. Thats what will do the trick! I'll just raise the `OnPropertyChanged` in the command. Thank you!

Comment: So if you do new ObservableCollection(list) and then it can't detect changes in list items(atleast add remove)..then its ridiculous implementation of ObservableCollection in C#.  move to(if possible) web/angular4, Rxjs it does this for you..

Comment: There comes a time in every programmer's life when they realize they're making things much harder on themselves than they need to.  At which point, they stop doing it.  Hopefully.

Comment: @Will I don't understand, how that fits my problem. I need a clean model without any MVVM related stuff and a ViewModel, that updates the View anyway

Comment: Well, you see, there comes a time in every programmer's life when they realize they're making things much harder on themselves than they need to.  At which point, they stop doing it.  Hopefully.

Comment: @Will Ok troll, enough food for today ;-)

Comment: Not trolling, just a little advice. Sometimes what you think you need, you really don't.  Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always keep the model class as a regular `List<>` and have the matching property on the View Model be an `ObservableCollection<>`.  I do this quite frequently without any issues.  In the constructor for the View Model (that takes the Model as an argument), I just instantiate the View Model's `ObservableCollection<>` from the contents of the property on the Model.  This works particularly well if you are actually wrapping *that* property `Type` too.

You **won't** get automatic updates on the View Model property when the Model property changes, so you will have to keep things in sync yourself, but I consider that part of the View Model's job anyway, especially when you are wrapping a Model that you do not control.

```
public void MyViewModel(MyModel<MyModelPropertyType> model)
{
    MyListProperty = new ObservableCollection<MyWrappedModelPropertyType>(model.ModelListProperty.Select(i => new MyWrappedModelPropertyType(i));
}
```

If you don't need to wrap the property type, you can omit the LINQ.  You will end up with some overhead from copying the list as far as instantiation time and memory cost.  If you need the property type wrapped, you would end up doing that any way though.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if there is a way to make the PluginValues collection in the Model of type List and still have the features of ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.

No. An `ObservableCollection<T>` implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and a `List<T>` doesn't.

So if you intend to dynamically add items to the `PluginValues` collection at runtime, this should be an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other kind of collection type that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

However, as pointed out in the comments, `ObservableCollection<T>` is not really a WPF specific class since it is defined in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace in `System.dll`. So you might use the `ObservableCollection<T>` as-is in your model or implement your own custom collection that raises notifications. The latter may seem a bit necessary though.

Comment: MVVM frameworks work without ObservableCollection just fine. You *don't* need ObservableCollection to get INotifyCollectionChanged  notifications - in fact, you *CAN'T* get such notifications from ObservableCollection in the most common case, when the property is set. ObservableCollection is just a helper

Comment: As for dynamically modifying the collection, that should be done through a Command or VM method, which can (and should) raise all the appropriate notifications. It's usually better to send all notifications at the end instead of raising a notification for every single item that's modified, forcing a repaint

Comment: If you are modifying the collection in the view model, you might as well add items to the wrapper ObservableCollection directly. Then you don't have an issue. But in this case I guess the *model* collection is updated dynamically in the model.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have any inheritance or other "forcing" relationship between your `Model` and `ViewModel`, so you have a few options:

**Option 1**

If there is no inheritance, you can have a properties with the same name, but different types in your models. Just be careful while mapping between those two classes.

**Option 2**

If the properties do need to have the same type, just use `IList<>` or `IEnumerable<>`.

```
IList<object> list1 = new ObservableCollection<object>();
IList<object> list2 = new List<object>();
```

All collections in C# implement `IList`, so all collections can be stored in a variable or property with the type `IList`. If you don't need any special list functions, like `Add`, `Clear`, `Contains`, etc, you could event use `IEnumerable<>` as property type.

**Option 3**

If there is inheritance between `Model` and `ViewModel`, properties can be overridden with the `new` keyword.

```
public class Model 
{
    public List<object> Plugins { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : Model 
{
    public new ObservableCollection<object> Plugins { get; set; }
}
```

The listing above is valid code and changes the type of `Plugin`. Just be aware that usage of the `new` keyboard can have some strange effects.

And assuming you use WPF (guess because of MVVM and C#) option 3 will not work. WPF uses reflection for databinding. If you overwrite a property with new, WPF will find two implementations and not knowing which one to use, it will throw an exception.

**Conclusion**

I personally prefer option 1. There is no reason why Models, DTOs and ViewModels should inherit from the same base and there is no reason why they can't have properties with the same name, but different types.

If you want you ViewModels to inherit from your Models, use option two.